# Faithfully Flat Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, flatness

I need some help to find faithfully flat abelian groups.

Flat abelian groups are torsion free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. But what about faithfully flat abelian groups. $\mathbb{Q}$ is an example that is torsionfree (flat) but not faithfully flat  $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

> How do we describe all faithfully flat abelian groups?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\mathbb Z$-module $M$ is faithfully flat iff it is torsion free and $pM\ne M$ for any prime number $p$.

Comment: I just realize that it is not so hard to think because of Q_Z. But i couldn't. Thanks again.